# How to add Text in the end of ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-image, picasso

I have a `ListFragment` in which I am downloading images using `picasso` in a `ListView`. Here is my `ArrayAdapter` code:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_dish_view, parent, false);
    }

    DrawLineTransformationation myTransformation = new DrawLineTransformationation() {
        @Override
        public String key() {
            return super.key();
        }
    };


    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load("http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg")
            .transform(myTransformation)
            .fit()
            .into((ImageView) convertView);
    return convertView;
}

private class DrawLineTransformationation implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public String key() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "drawline";
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (DrawLineTransformationation.class) {
            if(bitmap == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Bitmap resultBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_heart);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setTextSize(50);
            paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);

            canvas.drawText("$250", 10, 500, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, 900, 20, null);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return resultBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

## list_dish_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Roomimg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

If I run the above code I can see this [view](http://postimg.org/image/dtqq7fk55/). 
Now, I want to add text in the end of every Image and add a image on right bottom corner (So that half side would be on text description and other half is on big Image). See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kdMZ.png) example. You can see the text and profile picture in view. How can I achieve in my case?

Comment: Use a FrameLayout and place your text.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you provide me a little bit code snippet or pseudo code for using Framelayout? Because I am worried about current `bitmap`

Comment: if those images come from a PHP server you can prepare them like that using -- ImageMagick -  http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php  -- so you get them ready on the fly without doing anything in Android. I use this process for Map markers where i include an image on the Marker.

Comment: `FrameLayout` is the simplest ever layout container, whats unclear in it?

Comment: @pskink you are asking me to create a `Framelayout` in which I need to add `TextView` and `imageView`. What about the profile image? Problem is I have to download profile image using `picasso`

Comment: the profile image also inside a fame layout.. But think about doing the image processing on the server if you have one. You can stick png's on top of the main picture and send it ready without doing anything in Android. It will be quicker than downloading the assets

Comment: I don't have any option to do processing on server. So that's why I am using `picasso` transformation

Comment: Ok then use framelayouts. You put the images inside each one and position the frame where ever you want on top the main Picture. Also for the love icon

Comment: How to use `framelayout` to overlap (as I can see in profile picture) the image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following layout to achieve your design.  I had used negative margining in xml, If you want to avoid it, margin cant be set in activity after calculating it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:src="@drawable/matrix" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFF00FF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Some text........." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```